# Как определить оптимальное количество "эпох" для нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

**объёмом датасета:** 350.000 тысяч примеров

**количество категорий:** 95

**Архитектура нейронной сети:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(len(labels_lexicon), activation="softmax")
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=15,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=2)
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                        batch_size=128)
```

**Вопрос:**
Какое будет оптимальное кол-во "эпох" для обучения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Keras уже есть все необходимое для этого - используйте [Callbacks: `ModelCheckpoint` и `EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/callbacks/).

`ModelCheckpoint` - позволяет сохранять модель на диск в том случае если указанная метрика улучшилась после очередной эпохи.

`EarlyStopping` - позволяет досрочно завершить обучение если модель перестала обучаться / улучшаться.

Пример:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

Epochs = 300
Batch_size = 32

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001,
                           patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto')
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(model_filename, 
                        monitor='val_loss', 
                        verbose=1, 
                        save_best_only=True, 
                        mode='auto')
callbacks = [early_stop, chkpt]

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                 batch_size=Batch_size, epochs=Epochs, 
                 validation_data=(x_val, y_val), 
                 callbacks=callbacks)
```

---

как загрузить сохраненную модель с диска:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('/path/to/saved_model')
```

Comment: ModelCheckpoint сохраняет и веса и архитектуру в 1 файл как я понял?

Comment: `ModelCheckpoint` сохраняет объект `model` со всем содержимым

Comment: Как потом загрузить модель из такого файла?

Comment: Сейчас гружу модель так: `json_file = open("structure.json", "r")
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("weights_structure.h5")`

Comment: @СергейАндреев, я дополнил ответ...

Comment: зачем нужна вот эта: `EarlyStopping = 300` строчка?

Comment: @СергейАндреев, это опечатка - уже исправил

Comment: Спасибо за помощь